# Do a redirect in IIS, but show the original pretty url?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis

The following case:

A visitor comes in on `http://www.example.com/pretty`. This gets redirected to `http://www.example.com/?ID=ugly`. This part works.

However, we'd like the visitor to keep seeing `http://www.example.com/pretty` in the address bar of his browser, instead of `http://www.example.com/?ID=ugly`.

We've tried various combinations in the URL Rewrite module, but none seem to get us the desired result.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Presumably you've already tried `<action type="Rewrite"` as opposed to `"Redirect"`? Also bear in mind that if this was previously an external _redirect_, then it's likely that it was cached by the browser, so you will need to ensure all caches are cleared before testing.

Comment: We've tried quite a few permutations, yes  :)

Redirect http://www.example.com/pretty -> http://www.example.com/?ID=ugly shows the correct page, with the ugly URL.

Rewrite http://www.example.com/pretty -> http://www.example.com/?ID=ugly gives a 404.4 with the pretty URL.

Answer (score 1):

This eventually did the trick.
ugly URL: www.domain.com/?CatID=1167
pretty URL: www.domain.com/people

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect /people" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^catid=1167$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/people" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite /people" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^people$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="?catid=1167" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="OutboundRewrite /people" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" stopProcessing="false">
            <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="catid=1167$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="/people" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So, what actually was the problem with your original code?

Comment: Most likely something in the regex, the order, the patterns, or whatnot.

The above mentioned config we got by using the 'User-friendly URL' template, and butchering it in such a way that instead of turning 1 pattern into another pattern it would turn 1 specific URL into another one...  :)